# DISTINCT не работает если записи не по порядку

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть таблица с след. записями:

```
id    name    phone
1     Max     123
2     Bob     345
3     Max     123
```

Делаю:

```
Select distinct name, phone from table;
```

Получяю:

```
Max     123
Bob     345
Max     123
```

А если:

```
Select distinct name, phone from table where phone = 123;
```

Получаю:

```
Max     123
```

Но я ожидал получить в результате первого запроса первую и вторую строчки. А получил все три (первая и третья похожи)

Как такое может быть?

Distinct сравнивает следующюю запись с предыдущей?

Или он сравнивает следующюю запись со всеми существующими записями?

Comment: Вот пример, даже для Oracle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/428e3/1  это ваш запрос, на ваших же данных, он дает требуемый результат http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/428e3/1  то что вы привели в качестве результата может быть в случае, если в выборке была колонка ID, просто по каким то причинам ее нет на экране. Либо номер телефона (или имя) у вас текстовый и там закрался какой то пробел, и поэтому номера отличаются. Это легко проверить сделав `select phone, dump(phone) from table`

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70800/discussion-on-question-by-ks-on-v-distinct-------).

Comment: Попробуйте этот запрос: “Select distinct ‘|’||name||’|’, ‘|’||phone||’|’ from table;” - поправьте кавычки, это iPhone «красиво» сделал:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

За отсутствуем Oracle возьмём MySQL и создаём аналогичную таблицу:

```
CREATE TABLE `testing` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Добавим записи:

```
INSERT INTO `testing` (`id`, `name`, `phone`) VALUES 
    ('1', 'Max', '123'), ('2', 'Bob', '345'), ('3', 'Max', '123');
```

Сделаем запрос:

```
mysql> SELECT DISTINCT `name`, `phone` FROM `testing`;
+------+-------+
| name | phone |
+------+-------+
| Max  | 123   |
| Bob  | 345   |
+------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Получили ровно то, что ожидали.

Почему такой запрос мог не сработать? Самая очевидная причина: в колонках написано не то, что вы думаете, там написано. Например, в имени вместо латинской буквы `о` используется русская. Или в телефоне могут быть какие-то [невидимые символы](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-printing_character) вроде [U+200B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space).

Comment: Только не в имени, а в номере телефона. Иначе, вторая выборка, по  номеру телефона, тоже вернула бы 2 строки.

Comment: `INSERT` скорее не сработает, ибо `id` у Вас `AUTO_INCREMENT`, и участвовать в `Insert` он не должен. Я ошибаюсь?

Comment: @Viktorov Вы ошибаетесь

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик объясните, почему тогда второй запрос может возвращаеть 1 строку, а не две?

Comment: @Viktorov я думаю автор сам запутался в показаниях, а phone  у него интовый, иначе сравнение разных типов не сработало бы, по моему мнению.

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик, `Oracle` просто сделает неявное преобразование типов при сравнении разных типов. При этом конечно во время запроса могут упасть ошибки, если какое то поле привести не получится. Но разница в написании имени в любом случае ничего бы не изменила.

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик INSERT сработает такой, я всё проверил на живой БД

Comment: "За отсутствуем Oracle возьмём MySQL" - но вопрос по Oracle, и при его отсутствие под столом есть присутствие на ресурсах подобных  [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com).

Comment: @0xdb пишите уже свой ответ, чего вы ждёте?

Comment: @sanmai в смысле? Все уже написали, только меня не хватает?

Comment: @0xdb если все уже написали, то зачем был ваш комментарий?

Comment: @sanmai Мой комментарий о вашем ответе. Почему вы используете в ответе MySQL если вопрос касается Oracle?

Comment: @0xdb потому что вот так; не нравится? Видите кнопочку «вниз» слева от ответа? И ниже форму для своего ответа?

Answer (score 0):

`distinct` выводит **уникальные** записи, не важно в каком порядке они идут

```
id    name    phone
1     Max     123
2     Bob     345
3     Max     123
```

Уберите `id` из запроса

```
Select distinct name, phone from table;
```

Получите уникальные поля

```
Max     123
Bob     345
```

UPD (пояснение):
Возможно второй запрос у Вас выглядит так

```
Select distinct name, phone from table where phone = 123;
```

UPD2: 
Возможно в первом случае у Вас `Max` а во вором `Max(пробел)` или `Max(перенос проки)` или буквы на разных раскладках написаны, короче в любом из случаев строки не равны.

Comment: вы ответили на какой то другой вопрос. Вопрос о том, почему после дистинкта стало меньше полей

Comment: А извиняюсь, да, без id должно быть, поправил

Comment: @ks_on_v, а что должно измениться без ID, если вы в условии `where` указали номер телефона?

Comment: @Viktorov если id оставить, то строчки точно разные, а у меня строчки одинаковые выводятся через одну не похожую на них

Comment: @ks_on_v вы добавьте ожидаемый по вашему результат. А то не понятно, что вам не понятно)

Comment: @ks_on_v сейчас не понятно что имели ввиду, какая разница в каком порядке идут записи? `Distinct` выдаёт уникальные поля из всех в запросе.